# Как последовательно добавлять элементы на форму. Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Как пример можно привести будильник в любом телефоне, или моя проблема с менеджером. Мне нужно чтобы элементы добавлялись друг под другом.
Вот очень простой код с текстбоксом.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox myText = new TextBox();
    myText.Location = new Point(25, 25);
    this.Controls.Add(myText);
}
```

И если у вас есть рабочий пример сетевых взаимодействий на c# то буду признателен, если вы им со мной поделитесь.

Comment: По сетевым взаимодействиям чего с чем и по какому протоколу? Если HTTP - то рабочих примеров полно, ищите всё про `HttpClient`. Если что-то другое, то `TcpClient` или `UdpClient` или какой-нибудь специальный NuGet пакет вам в помощь.

Comment: Я делаю тестовый мессенджер для себя и друзей. Что-то для проектов такого типа.

Comment: В любом случае, это можно делать в разных позах. Выберите протокол и ищите примеры, свободы для творчества очень много. Лично я бы ради развлечения и расширения кругозора поигрался с UDP.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте FlowLayoutPanel c  FlowDirection.TopDown, тогда элементы будут располагаться сверху вниз

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var flowPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel()
    {
        FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown,
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    };
           
     this.Controls.Add(flowPanel);
     flowPanel.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
     flowPanel.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
}
```

> И если у вас есть рабочий пример сетевых взаимодействий на c# то буду
> признателен, если вы им со мной поделитесь.

Ну а это совсем другая и достаточно обширная история ) совтеую сформулировать более четкие вопросы, с конкретикой что вам нужно и создать новый вопрос.